# Django urlencode template filter

Tags: django, templates, filter, urlencode

I'm attempting to URL encode a string that contains slashes in Django 1.3 using the optional argument [shown in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode):

```
{{ someString|urlencode:"" }}
```

However, the slashes aren't getting URL encoded, they're left intact. So, if someString is "A/V Equipment", I'm getting "A/V%20Equipment". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind - it helps to do it everywhere you need it... :P

Answer (score 1):

"/" is already a valid url character and as such will not be encoded to something else.  You are not doing anything wrong.  I take it you are having issues with some sort of clean url argument that gets confused with the / character? If this is the case, rather pass the string in as a query parameter.